# Jquery Setinterval + One()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage where I use the Lazyload plugin to load a bunch of product images. And I also use the Lightslider plugin. Which creates a gallary slider for each product. This is fine.

But when scrolled the images are not loaded before, so the lightslider is not called again of course.

This is why I tried to use Setinterval to call on the lightslider every 2 second or so.

But by calling it more than once it creates a new slider on the same element every 2 second.

So how do i use Setinterval + the one function so it only does it once per element?

This is my code so far.

```
function($) {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $(".lightslider").lightSlider();
    }, 2000);
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: `window.setTimeout()` will execute you function only once is that is what you want: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Have you tried the solution mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/issues/175)?

Comment: Your lazy loader plugin should expose some events you can hook to when content has been added - at least it should if it's a good one. If it doesn't, get a better one. You can then initialise the `lightSlider()` within that callback

Comment: sounds like you need a better selector or plan of attack.

Comment: No i need to it to execute each time a it loads some new products, but It shouldn't dublicate on the old products

Comment: Im using LazySizes and im not sure where to do it. 

@vahdet yes didn't work

Comment: "i need to it to execute each time a it loads some new products"...doesn't the loader plugin expose an event which is triggered when this happens, and which you can listen to? As Rory said, a good plugin would do something like that. Just regularly polling it in the hope that something has changed is not very efficient and doesn't allow you to properly track what has been loaded since the last time you polled